# Run annotation processor before every method invocation in a service

Tags: java, api, annotations, interceptor, annotation-processing

I am building a service with RestAPI's. I want to put a custom annotation as mentioned below.

```
@CustomAnnnotation
public APIResponse apiMethod(APIRequest request) {

}
```

### Functionality of this custom annotation :

Whenever there is a request to this apiMethod, before the execution of this method , i want to call an API in different server with some of the request parameters from this function. Example mentioned below. Basically for every method invocation i want to call a different server.

#### Instead of doing this

```
public APIResponse apiMethod(APIRequest request) {
    newServiceClient.newAPI(request.getName())
}
```

I want to do this functionality by using a custom annotation. I know that i can use interceptors to intercept this request and call the API. Is there any other way ?

### Edit :

To summarise this question. There is a method(This might not be API start point. It can also be a normal method in your application) in my java code. Whenever i annotate this method, for every invocation of this method in application, i want do some functionality. I want to have this in annotation because i am thinking of providing a library for this annotation so that any function can be annotated

Comment: You can use Spring AOP if you are using the Spring Framework.

Comment: I am not using spring framework. Basically i want to do some functionality on every method call in java , if there is annotation present on the method

Comment: What framework you are using building your application

Comment: It shouldn't depend on framework right ? Let me ask it this way. There is a method(This might not be API start point. It can also be a normal method in your application) in my java code. Whenever i annotate this method, for every invocation of this method in application, i want do some functionality

Comment: You are simply trying to build a proxy, so implementing a proxy pattern, the proxy implementation can be generated and injected in replace of the original one